# convert image strings from an array into images in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, wordpress

Im trying to set up a page on my site that has all the images from the media library on it shuffled up in a random order.

As of now I have the strings in a really long array and was wondering how I could turn them into images and "shuffle" them or maybe query them in a random order first and then convert them?

Have been stuck on this for awhile so any tips would be good.

Here is a link to the site http://ownc.co.nz/random/

Cheers

```
            <?php $query_images_args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1, );

            $query_images = new WP_Query($query_images_args);
            $images = array();
            foreach ($query_images->posts as $image) {
                $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url($image -> ID);
            }

            var_dump($images);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To randomize your images you can add 'orderby' argument to WP_Query with the value of 'rand'
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters
alternatively you can shuffle the array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

As far as converting I am not sure what you mean, if you have an array of urls than just do an image tag with the source of the url:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $img): ?> 
<img src="<?php echo $img?>">
<?endforeach; ?>
```